# "Auch" an erster Stelle im Satz

Tags: sentence-structure

In einer *wissenschaftlichen Arbeit* lese ich vermehrt solche Sätze:

> Auch stellt der Gebrauch von (...) einen klaren Verstoß... dar.
>
> Auch erhält die Kommunikation (...)  ihren typischen (...) Anstrich.

Mir kommt solche Struktur etwas seltsam vor, da es in meinen Ohren irgendwie nicht nach "gutem Deutsch" klingt.
Sind solche Sätze angemessen oder nicht?

Comment: Klassisch: "Auch du mein Sohn Brutus?" - War damals schon erlaubt ;)

Comment: @tofro - Die beiden Konstruktionen sind nicht vergleichbar, oder? Hieße es "Auch trachtest du mir nach dem Leben, Brutus!", dann vielleicht. Für mich ist das typisch hölzerne Wissenschaftssprache: Sie ersetzt das natürlich klingende "zudem" durch das vermeintlich neutralere "auch". Falsch ist es nicht, besonders schön klingt es auch nicht, zumal wenn regelmäßig und schemenhaft verwendet.

Comment: @EndreBoth "Falsch ist es nicht. Auch klingt es nicht besonders schön". Einen Satz mit einer Konjunktion (auch, aber) zu beginnen, gilt als stilistisch unschön. Mit einem Adverb wie hier habe ich aber keinerlei Problem. Wir haben im Deutschen eine große Flexibilität in der Wortreihenfolge - Die sollten wir auch nutzen. Das heißt natürlich nicht, daß jeder zweite Satz mit "auch" anfangen sollte.

Comment: @EndreBoth: Was an "auch" hölzerner sein soll als an "zudem" bzw. was an "zudem" natürlicher klingen soll als an "auch" musst du nun aber erklären. Ehrlich gesagt scheint mir "zudem" eher gehobenes Schriftdeutsch zu sein, während das Wort "auch" durchaus auch in der gesprochenen Sprache häufig vorkommt, und somit durchaus als "natürlich" eingestuft werden kann.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Der erste Satz sollte

> Auch ist der Gebrauch von (...) ein klarer Verstoß...

lauten. Dann ist das völlig in Ordnung, nur sollte sich der Gebrauch solcher Formulierungen nicht häufen. (Der vorhergehende Satz nach dem Komma hat eine ähnliche Struktur.) Eine Alternative wäre beispielsweise:

> Hinzu kommt, dass der Gebrauch von (...) ein klarer Verstoß (...) ist.

Das erscheint mir nicht besser.

Comment: "Dann ist das völlig in Ordnung" - warum ist es denn mit der ursprünglichen Wortwahl nicht in Ordnung? Also, wieso ist "der Gebrauch ist" besser als "der Gebrauch stellt ... dar"?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper, die Frage ist verändert worden.

Comment: Ach ja, so ein Fall mal wieder. Dann ist mir die Bemerkung in der Antwort klar.